# awk command not working with kubectl exec

Tags: awk

From outside container:

```
$ kubectl exec -it ui-gateway-0 -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1"
root         14      9  0 10:34 ?        00:00:02 /svc/bin/entities_api_svc

$ kubectl exec -it ui-gateway-0 -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'"
root         14      9  0 10:34 ?        00:00:02 /svc/bin/entities_api_svc
```

From inside container:

```
[root@ui-gateway-0 /]# ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
14
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to use single quotes on the `sh`/`bash` command argument so it is closer to what you would type in the shell:

```
kubectl exec -it ui-gateway-0 -- \
  bash -c 'ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1 | awk "{print \$2}"'
```

This means the `awk` uses double quotes, which requires the shell variable marker `$` to be escaped.

In the original command, the shell running `kubectl` was replacing `$2` with a zero length string so awk would see only `print`, which prints the whole line

#### Multiple levels of nesting

Nested shell escaping gets very obscure very quickly and hard to debug:

```
$ printf '%q\n' 'echo "single nested $var" | awk "print $2"'
echo\ \"single\ nested\ \$var\"\ \|\ awk\ \"print\ \$2\"

$ printf '%q\n' "$(printf '%q\n' 'echo "double nested $var" | awk "print $2"')"
echo\\\ \\\"double\\\ nested\\\ \\\$var\\\"\\\ \\\|\\\ awk\\\ \\\"print\\\ \\\$2\\\"
```

If you add a file `grep-entities.sh` in container

```
#!/bin/bash
set -uex -o pipefail
ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

You then don't need to worry about escaping

```
pid=$(sshpass -p "password" ssh vm@10.10.0.1 kubectl exec ui-gateway-0 -- /grep-entities.sh)
```

Also [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) does the scripts job for you

```
kubectl exec ui-gateway-0 -- pgrep entities_api_svc
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I have 2 questions.
In my original command, why did it replace $2. I thought anything in single quotes won't be replaced.
Second, going with your rightful way, how would you do it if I need another set of quotes. Say: `pid=$(sshpass -p "password" ssh vm@10.10.0.1 "kubectl exec ui-gateway-0 -- bash -c 'ps -ef | grep entities_api_svc | head -1 | awk \"{print \$2}\"'")`

Comment: The double quotes on the outside are all that matters to your local shell when it does the first layer of variable substitution. The single quotes then do as you expect in the containers shell, but the `$2` is already gone by then.

Comment: Another level of escaping is where I start writing scripts to deploy to the VM or container so I don't have to deal with escaping.

Comment: Got the first one. What do you mean by the second one :/

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thanks Matt! pgrep would make it easier. I got your point to keep things simple. As you see, in my command, I don't want the execution to happen from inside to outside, that won't fulfil the purpose. I looked around a bit, and found that mostly people do the same way as you told: to make another script. I can't make a script inside the container. Is there really no way to make the above command in the comments work, it has the same problem with $2 not being escaped. I am just curious to know.